# Is it possible to give a different name to a package dependency in pubspec

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I managed to add a relative path dependency in my app

```
name: myapp
description: A sample app
dependencies:
  mylib:
    path: ../mylib
```

and then import it in my source code

```
import 'package:mylib/mylib.dart';
```

However, the name 'mylib' is taken from the library package pubspec and if I want to change it (for example 'mynewlib'), I have to change the name everywhere (pubspec AND dart source code)

It also prevent having 2 packages with the same name (yes I know, weird, but I don't control what people put in pub.dartlang.org). What I'd like to do is something like

```
name: myapp
description: A sample app
dependencies:
  mylib:
    path: ../mylib
    name: mynewlib
```

and have in source code

```
import 'package:mynewlib/mylib.dart';
```

However I cannot find the proper syntax and whether that's possible or not. (Sample code ready for testing is here: https://github.com/alextekartik/dart-test/tree/master/lib_test). To note that here I'm not talking about library name but package name (and naming the package mylib can be confusing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to define another name for a package itself (as far as I know - if there is, I'd be interested too).

However, as a workaround, you could rewrap it. For example, let's assume you have two "mylib" packages.

Create a new library application "mylib1". There, you import the first "mylib" and reexport it using `export`. Create another library application "mylib2" for the other "mylib". Then you have different package names to use in the same application.

Yes, it is kinda awkward, but as long as there is no better way...

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I created a feature request https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10940

Answer (score -1):

You can resolve name conflicts at import with:

```
import 'package:mylib/mylib.dart' as Foo;
```

This will create a top level name to access the library API:

```
Foo.bar();
```

Comment: As I said at the end of my question, I'm not talking about library name but package name. It is indeed great to allow 'as Xxx' for library name to have something similar to a namespace. However, if I have 2 packages with the same name or if I want to change a package name without going through all the files, I cannot find a solution